# Thanking panel interviews by email, individual or group?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism

I had just completed a panel interview and found out that it is important to thank the interviewers (regardless of outcome), as mentioned [here](https://www.businessinsider.com/who-you-send-the-thank-you-letter-during-group-interviews-the-ladders-2012-11), amongst many other sources.
I have the email addresses of each of the interviewers.

During the interview, there were many discussions around many common themes, and it was more like a conversation with every person contributing some points rather than strictly a Q and A between myself and the interviewers.

Given the inclusiveness of the discussions, would it be better to send a group thank you email to all the interviewers rather than individual emails to each interviewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From on Andrew Lacivita's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EvDlk0NK8M), from around the 9:00 mark, he states:

> Do not send a group thank you email, it does nothing to connect you to the individuals themselves, it will make them feel like one of many.

He then goes on to suggesting individual letters where the beginning (thank you) and end (excited for the opportunity, look forward to hearing from you) are the same, but with differences in the middle (why you are suitable) that's tailored to the individual.

Comment: We use a three person panel interview style while recruiting and one of our candidates recently took this exact approach. The other two interviewers and myself all commented to each other how impressive it was after reading our own tailored thank you emails. It definitely made the candidate stand out from the rest.